# Kafka cluster with many smaller brokers or fewer larger ones?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, messagebroker, aws-msk

I'm building a Kafka cluster in [MSK](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/). With that, I have the option of choosing broker count and broker VM size. [There is no cost difference](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/pricing/) between, for instance, 6 `kafka.m5.4xlarge` vs 3 `kafka.m5.8xlarge`, where the `8xlarge` is twice the vCPU and RAM of the `4xlarge`.

The only concrete example I can find is [an AWS blog where Intuit uses 12 brokers of `r3.xlarge`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-running-apache-kafka-on-aws/) (4 vCPU / 32 GiB RAM), but they don't mention any performance differences between that and say, 24 `r3.large` or 6 `r3.2xlarge`. Does anyone know of any heuristics on this front? Does it just come down to partition count (which in turn [depends on desired throughput and latency](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/)), or are there other factors I should pay attention to?

Comment: Given that memory is all contained within the JVM, and there's little reason to go beyond `-Xmx` 6-8GB, there's not much benefit to having a lot of RAM per instance. More vCPU for threads is always nice. Obviously more brokers allows more throughout and higher fault tolerance, at the cost of more maintenance and longer upgrade cycles